# Angular2 создать Dom вписать значения из массива

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Добрый день, с Angular работаю впервые, пока кажется очень сложным и непонятным, но работать приходится, возникла проблема, Необходимо создавать DOM в количестве строк в массиве и подпихивать туда значения, из массива,DOM создается корректно но значения не подставляются.
 . Вот собственно код:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of data">
  <div class="application-name-block flex-item" onclick="location.href='{{ data[i].HOSTURL }}'">
    <div class="application-block flex-item">
      <img src="../../assets/{{ data[i].APPNAME }}" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <span class="application-name">{{ data[i].APPICON }}</span>
  </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Где data это массив вотт такого плана из 14 строк

```
0:{APPID: 1, APPNAME: "IR Admin", APPCODE: "IR_ADMIN", APPICON: "iRadmin.png", HOSTURL: "http://portal.ru.auchan.com", …}
```

Comment: `data` тут объект, а не массив и вы немного неправильно понимаете ngFor. Поправьте вопрос, как у вас точно выглядит `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `*ngFor="let i of data"` `i` будет последовательно принимать значения массива `data`, это не индекс. Либо далее в шаблоне вместо `data[i].xxx` используйте `i.xxx` либо поменяйте цикл на примерно такой `*ngFor="let d of data; let i = index"` - в этом случае `i` будет именно текущим индексом.

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor

Comment: Да спасибо уже разобрался=)